# Question about __get() and __set() in php

Tags: php, class

As I understand, when you define __get and __set functions in php, the way of reaching attributes don't change. I mean

```
class something {

    public $world;
    public $hello;

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this - > $name;
    }

    public function _set($name, $value) {
        $this - > $name = $value;
    }
}
```

Now I am wondering what I am gonna do if I don't want `$hello` to call `__get` and `__set` functions implicitly when I reach it, only for `$world`;

What I want is would look like this one in C#

```
   class something {
        public string world;
        public string hello{get;set;}
    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: so you mean you don't want $something->__set('hello')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any unaccessible properties will automatically call `__get` and `__set`, therefore, set `$world` to `private`.

Comment: unaccessible or accessible? I mean lets say `$a = new something(); echo $a->$hello;` and I don't want `$hello` to call `__get` and `__set`.

Comment: Haven't you tried it already? `__get`/`__set` won't be called because `$hello` is a defined, public property. [Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).